# This code only works on iPhone Retina 4-inch simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

I'm developing an iOS 5+ application with latest SDK and I have a custom `UIView` with a custom `XIB`.

This is `TopMenuView.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TopMenuView : UIView

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *MenuButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *MenuLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *SearchButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *ProfileButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *HomeButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) UIViewController* parentController;

- (IBAction)MenuClicked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)SearchClicked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)ProfileClicked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)HomeClicked:(id)sender;

+ (id)topMenuView;

@end
```

This is `TopMenuView.m`:

```
#import "TopMenuView.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "ProfileViewController.h"
#import "HomeViewController.h"

#import "SWRevealViewController.h"

@implementation TopMenuView

@synthesize parentController;

+ (id)topMenuView
{
    TopMenuView* topView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TopMenuView"
                                                          owner:nil
                                                        options:nil] lastObject];
    // make sure customView is not nil or the wrong class!
    if ([topView isKindOfClass:[TopMenuView class]])
    {
        [topView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 49)];
        return topView;
    }
    else
        return nil;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark IBAction methods

- (IBAction)MenuClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self.parentController.revealViewController revealToggle:sender];
}

- (IBAction)SearchClicked:(id)sender
{
    SearchViewController* search =
        [[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController"
                                               bundle:nil];

    [self.parentController.revealViewController setFrontViewController:search];
}

- (IBAction)ProfileClicked:(id)sender
{
    ProfileViewController* profile =
        [[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyProfileViewController"
                                                bundle:nil];

    [self.parentController.revealViewController setFrontViewController:profile];
}

- (IBAction)HomeClicked:(id)sender
{
    HomeViewController* home =
        [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController"
                                             bundle:nil];

    [self.parentController.revealViewController setFrontViewController:home];
}

@end
```

And on `UIViewController` I do this to show it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    topMenuView = [TopMenuView topMenuView];
    topMenuView.MenuLabel.text = @"Home";
    topMenuView.parentController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:topMenuView];

    // Set the gesture to open the slide menu.
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}
```

And this is the view:

[image]

This code works perfectly only on iPhone Retina 4-inch **simulator**. On iPhone Retina 3.5-inch and on iPhone simulator, it doesn't work.

The problem is that I do a click over any of that "buttons" it do nothing. No Touch Inside Up event is throw (I set a debug point inside the IBAction method).

I haven't test it on a real iPhone because I don't have a developer license yet.

**What's happening?** Why it doesn't work on iPhone 3.5-inch?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have another view which covers over your buttons.  Check your xib file for a view that is possibly being expanded by the system when it has a different size screen.

Comment: I think if I have another view that covers my `TopMenuView` it wouldn't work in any of the simulators.

Comment: Something is capturing your touch up events, and it's probably another view. I'm figuring the view isn't long enough to cover the buttons on the 4 inch screen, but long enough to cover the 3.5 inch screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Everything worked fine, until I uncheck "Use AutoLayout" button in Storyboard. I have UIView with button placed on it. And have action related to this button. Then in iPhone Retina 3.5-inch Simulator it doesn't respond to that action.
Finally, I found the solution in the Storyboard. It sets the height of my view where button is placed to 0. I don't know why. So I just specify its height programmatically.
Hope this will help!